# cross browser HTML5 javascript generate single tick sound

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I need a single-shot square wave of approximately 20 ms width.
I have not found a simple autonomous code sample to do this.

Without external libraries and with only a couple of lines of code
can this be done?  It was easy to do on an IBM XT running DOS.
I did an extended search with creative keywords but found nothing.

I saw a hint that one can construct a sound locally
(replacing ...data... with actual data):

```
var playSound = (function beep () {
    var snd = new Audio ("data:audio/wav;base64,//...data...");
    return function () {     
        snd.play(); 
    }
}) ();
```

and then running:

```
playSound ();
```

But these examples didn't work.
I have chrome, firefox, opera, and a couple of other browsers.

Does anyone know how to do this without much code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) provides a set of interesting tools for audio processing which I've used to produce a 226.6hz 20ms square wave below.

**Update** Web Audio oscillator notes can only be started and stopped once. This is a design <s>flaw</s> feature that requires creating a new ocillator node each time one is played.

I've also included master and oscillator gain controls so show interconnection of audio nodes.

```js
// create audio context, masterGain and nodeGain1 nodes

var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
//  ( "Webkit/blink browsers need prefix, Safari won't work without window.")

var masterGain = audioContext.createGain();
    masterGain.gain.value = 0.5;
masterGain.connect(audioContext.destination);

var nodeGain1 = audioContext.createGain();
    nodeGain1.gain.value = 0.5;
nodeGain1.connect(masterGain);

function clickBuzz( frequency, length) {
    var oscillatorNode = new OscillatorNode(audioContext, {type: 'square'});
    oscillatorNode.frequency.value = frequency;
    oscillatorNode.connect( nodeGain1);
    oscillatorNode.start(audioContext.currentTime);
    //setTimeout( function(){oscillatorNode.stop();}, length*1000);
    oscillatorNode.stop( audioContext.currentTime + length);
}

function volume1( rangeInput) {
    masterGain.gain.value = +rangeInput.value;
}

function volume2( rangeInput) {
    nodeGain1.gain.value= +rangeInput.value;
}
```

```html
<p>Type in the textarea for keypress sounds:</p>
<textarea onkeydown="clickBuzz( 261.6, 0.020)"></textarea>
<p>
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="0.5" style="width: 200px" onchange="volume1(this)" onkeypress="volume1(this)"> master volume
</p><p>
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="0.5" style="width: 200px" onchange="volume2(this)" onkeyup="volume2(this)"> oscillator volume
</p>
```

The above code  works in Firefox and Chrome, and MDN provides more information on [browser compatability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API#Browser_compatibilityhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API#Browser_compatibility).

The timing accuracy of starting and stopping oscillators with the code as written is of concern: it sometimes abbreviates or drops click sounds. Possibly `start` starts playing sound asynchronously and any accumulated delays in starting to play are coming out of total play length, but I have not fully investigated the issue (`setTimeout` was less prone to the problem than `stop`).

Comment: If you are concerned about browser support why do you use the OscillatorNode constructor, supported only by latests chrome and FF instead of the legacy [AudioContext.createOscillator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createOscillator) method, which is supported by all major browsers?

Comment: It's a lot of code to do such a simple thing.  But it worked.  Thanks.